# Easiest way for a simple 3d app

Tags: c#, c++, math, actionscript, 3d

A friend of mine asked for a simple program.

Input: Coordinates of some points, spheres, planes etc. ( from an excel document (strictly) )

Output: A 3D view of the input which the user can move the camera.

The questions is, how can I do that easiest way. I have experience in C++, C#, Flash (AS), Java

Comment: Easiest way: find another friend who can do it faster than you can research it ;-)

Comment: With friends like that who needs enemies?  This is not going to be a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Input: Coordinates of some points,
>   spheres, planes etc. ( from an excel
>   document (strictly) )

This is going to be your major problem, reading an excel document from Flash is not an easy task. You will either have to process it on a server side script with XML/JSON/AMF output to the client, or simply give up on the format.

> Output: A 3D view of the input which
>   the user can move the camera.

Displaying 3D objects in flash is easy using one of [Papervision3D](http://blog.papervision3d.org/) or [Away3D](http://away3d.com/).

Comment: Actually I have done some simple 3D work with flash in the past but as you mentioned, it's not easy to read from excel.

Comment: You aren't restricted to Flash, are you?

Comment: No, I was just replying the answer about flash.

Comment: Since it´s not production software, but for a friend. Why not a mix. Write a conversion tool in c++/c#/whatever and convert it to a flash friendly format. Maybe it´s already out there by xls->save as xml->some tool convert to flash friendly format.

Comment: Or just save as csv... but you mentioned "strictly" from Excel, so I wish you luck :)

Comment: There are lots of easy way to get the data out of excel. For example, xlrd (http://scienceoss.com/read-excel-files-from-python/), openpyxl (http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/). Find more at http://www.python-excel.org/

Answer (score 0):

There's a good book called XNA 3.0 Game Programming Recipes by Riemer Grootjans.  You can find sample applications at his site: http://www.riemers.net/.

Comment: Did you even *read* his question?!